# Grails filter stops working after

Tags: session, grails, before-filter

I have a filter set up as follow to control users login status.

```
class SecurityFilters {
  def filters = {
    login(controller:'login|logout|proxy|API|error', action:'*', invert: true) {
      before = {
        if (!session.isLoggedIn){
          switch(controllerName){
            case "enroll":
              switch(actionName){
                ...
                default:
                  log.warn "Permission Denied. Default action for enroll."
                  render(view: '/permissionDenied', model: [message: "You must be logged in to access the enroll system.  If you are a consumer, please contact your agent for more information."])
                  break
              }
              break
          ...

        }
        else {
          switch(controllerName){
            case "agent":
              if (!session.user.isAgent) {
                render view: "/permissionDenied", model: [message: 'This portion of the site is only available to agents.']
                return false
              }
              break

            ....
          }// switch
        }// else
      }// before
      ...
    }// login
  }// filters
```

The problem I am having is that when I run this in development it works fine but when I run it on our QA system it works fine for a while and then suddenly it stops working correctly.

I added logging and I can see that the session information is available in the filter and the session variable (session.user.isAgent) is set correctly (true) but the code inside the if(!session.user.isAgent) gets executed regardless.

I can's seem to find the cause for odd behaviour.

My question is has anyone seen this behaviour before and how did they solve it or have any ideas of where to look for probable cause for the sudden change in the way the filter is working.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE** (02/19/2014):
After adding more logging in an effort to hunt down the cause the filter did not execute the code in the if(!session.user.isAgent) as it was doing before. Now it runs normally and then executes only the render line for when the user is not logged in. The logging still show that the user is logged in and that (s)he is an agent but then it runs the render but not the lines of code above it. It is as if there was a "goto" the render line after it completes checking if the agent is logged in.

Again any information or solution would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I've had a few issues with filters and Groovy truth. The problem I was seeing was that no errors were logged, even with aggressive exception catching (i.e. catching Throwable) and the only output in the browser was a blank page. This seems to happen only in Filters- everywhere else the errors get logged.

In my case, the issue was down to Groovy truth. I was trying to set a Boolean attribute on the session, but every time I did this it failed. In the end I had to convert the value to a String, and then set it, and it worked.

I know this isn't a direct answer, but I've been bitten a few times by the above and for example, lazy GString evaluation.

If you're still debugging, I'd log some output showing the underlying Class type of what you think you're dealing with. It may be that when your boolean conditions are evaluated above an exception is being thrown and swallowed. I'd log the actual values of each of your conditional statements to see what they are. Also remove each line one by one, to see if the failure goes away. And/or replace your conditionals with absolute values i.e. true/false to see if the code gets executed. If it does, it points to an error in the current conditional evaluation.

Comment: After further research I think this might have been a bug that was resolved in 2.3 but unfortunately I cannot upgrade the grails version to this project due to it being placed into maintenance mode. My temporary solution was to just add the check at the top of each controller method. Ugly but it gets the job done.